# Can a DOM element attribute value be a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Maybe this is a duplicate, but I could find the similar question.

For example we have `<input data-student="">` and we have a `var studentObj = {...}`. Can I assign `studentObj` to input `data-student` attribute? Will it contradict the standards?

Comment: [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*): _"Forms a class of attributes, called custom data attributes, that allow proprietary information to be exchanged between the HTML and its DOM representation that may be used by scripts."_

Comment: What you are looking for is the dataset attribute. Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: No, `dataSet` is a map of strings (both keys and values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Attribute* values are always strings, so no. You have several options:

1. Store the object in string form, such as JSON, in the attribute.
2. Store the object in a container somewhere and keep a key for it in the attribute.
3. If you mean on an element instance, it's *possible* to add your own properties to element instances, and those properties can have any value (search for "expando properties" for details), but be sure to use a name that will be really, really specific to your situation. (jQuery does this, for example, for the data it manages via the `data` function.)

   - And in fact, if you're using jQuery, you could use `data` to store the object, leaving the details to jQuery. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sure will! HTML doesn't accept a data type of object, it is in fact just plain text

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `dataset` attribute. But it only stores strings, you can solve this with JSON.

`el.dataset.student = JSON.stringify(studentObj);`

`studentObj = JSON.parse(el.dataset.student);`

With jquery's `data` method (https://api.jquery.com/data/) you can store objects without any further problems.

Read more:

Dataset: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset -

JSON: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: *"What you are looking for is the dataset attribute. But it only stores strings"* So...clearly **not** what the OP is looking for, as the OP is looking to store an object. (jQuery's `data`, on the other hand, is relevant -- if the OP is using jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your desire doesn't contradict the standards, you must `stringify` your object and put in your data attribute then in usage `parse` it, like below:

```
const q = document.querySelector.bind(document); // it's just for easiness

const input = q('input'); //select the input

const studentObj = { // make your student object
    something: 'some-value'
};

input.dataset.student = JSON.stringify(studentObj);
// put the student object in your selected input data attribute
```

When you wanna use it you can `parse` it:

```
const input = q('input'); //select the input

const myDesireObject = JSON.parse(input.dataset.student);
```